# Code does not execute

Tags: c#, file, for-loop

I know I've been a bit of pain, the last couple of days, that is, with all my questions, but I've been developing this project and I'm (figuratively) inches away from finishing it.

That being said, I would like your help on one more matter. It kind of relates to my previous questions, but you do not need the code for those. The problem lies exactly on this bit of code. What I want from you is to help me identify it and, consequently, solve it.

Before I show you the code I'd been working on, I'd like to say a few extra things:

1. My application has a file merging feature, merging two files together and handling duplicate entries.
2. In any given file, each line can have one of these four formats (the last three are optional): `Card Name|Amount`, `.Card Name|Amount`, `..Card Name|Amount`, `_Card Name|Amount`.
3. If a line is not appropriately formatted, the program will skip it (ignore it altogether).

So, basically, a sample file could be as follows:

```
Blue-Eyes White Dragon|3
..Blue-Eyes Ultimate Dragon|1
.Dragon Master Knight|1
_Kaibaman|1
```

Now, when it comes to using the file merger, if a line starts with one of the special characters `. .. _`, it should act accordingly. For `.`, it operates normally. For lines starting with `..`, it moves the index to the second dot and, finally, it ignores `_` lines completely (they have another use not related to this discussion).

Here is my code for the merge function (for some odd reason, the code inside the second loop won't execute at all):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Save file names to array.
    string[] fileNames = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

    // Loop through the files.
    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    {
        // Save all lines of the current file to an array.
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        // Loop through the lines of the file.
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Split current line.
            string[] split = lines[i].Split('|');

            // If the current line is badly formatted, skip to the next one.
            if (split.Length != 2)
                continue;

            string title = split[0];
            string times = split[1];

            if (lines[i].StartsWith("_"))
                continue;

            // If newFile (list used to store contents of the card resource file) contains the current line of the file that we're currently looping through...
            for (int k = 0; k < newFile.Count; k++)
            {
                if (lines[i].StartsWith(".."))
                {
                    string newTitle = lines[i].Substring(
                        lines[i].IndexOf("..") + 1);

                    if (newFile[k].Contains(newTitle))
                    {
                        // Split the line once again.
                        string[] secondSplit = newFile.ElementAt(
                            newFile.IndexOf(newFile[k])).Split('|');
                        string secondTimes = secondSplit[1];

                        // Replace the newFile element at the specified index.
                        newFile[newFile.IndexOf(newFile[k])] =
                            string.Format("{0}|{1}", newTitle, int.Parse(times) + int.Parse(secondTimes));
                    }
                    // If newFile does not contain the current line of the file we're looping through, just add it to newFile.
                    else
                        newFile.Add(string.Format(
                                        "{0}|{1}",
                                        newTitle, times));

                    continue;
                }

                if (newFile[k].Contains(title))
                {
                    string[] secondSplit = newFile.ElementAt(
                        newFile.IndexOf(newFile[k])).Split('|');
                    string secondTimes = secondSplit[1];

                    newFile[newFile.IndexOf(newFile[k])] =
                        string.Format("{0}|{1}", title, int.Parse(times) + int.Parse(secondTimes));
                }
                else
                {
                    newFile.Add(string.Format("{0}|{1}", title, times));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Overwrite resources file with newFile.
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CardResources.ygodc"))
    {
        foreach (string line in newFile)
            sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

I know this is quite a long piece of code, but I believe all of it is relevant to a point. I skipped some unimportant bits (after all of this is executed) as they are completely irrelevant.

Comment: I have spent way too much time reading this kind of code in order to find the needle in the haystack. You really need to start using techniques from Clean Code etc. to make your code much more readable and thus much less error-prone in the first place. I know it is not the answer to your question but it will help you in the long run understanding and debugging your own code.

Comment: @meilke I understand that my code is not the easiest to understand. Since I started teaching myself how to program, I (wrongfully) adopted the stance of "if it works, it works", without emphasizing much on the structure of my code. Will definitely look into that, friend.

Comment: Where does newFile get set? Is newFile empty?

Comment: When the form's load event occurs, the program loops through the resources file and assigns newFile each line of it. So, to answer your question, resources file = empty => newFile = empty. But that shouldn't be a problem since if the function doesn't find a match, it will just add it to newFile.

Comment: Both of the nested loops rely on a variable that is initialized to 0 and are controlled by a condition of either one being < a length or a count. For loops will execute so have you put a breakpoint to see if either of those things are zero?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? I mean do step by step and watch the value of your variables `lines.Length`, `newFile.Count` ... That may help you understand why you are not entering your loops. We don't know the content of your files.

Comment: Jim, it doesn't work like that.  If newFile starts out empty, you'll never enter the second for loop in the first place, so the code that adds things to newFile never gets executed.  Anyway that second for loop looks wrong for what you want to accomplish right now.  Move all that logic outside the second for loop and get rid of the second for-loop completely.  Instead do the check in a more "advanced" (except it's actually easier) using Linq Any (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) - bool shouldDoMyStuff = newList.Any(newListItem => newListItem.contains(newTitle);